# change character ก to Ď during xls2csv -d utf-8 /source.xls >desination.csv

Tags: utf-8, thai

When I convert an XLS file to CSV using xls2csv there is a problem that the character 'ก' is converted to 'Ď'.

My command is:

```
xls2csv -d utf-8 /test.xls>/test.csv
```

Other characters of Thai and other languages work normally.

Comment: That's interesting. The code points of `ก` and `Ď` are `0E01` and `010E`, respectively. The swapped digits look suspicious, this might be a bug in the tool. Are you talking about [this one](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xls2csv)?

Comment: Yes,  you are getting my point exactly what i want to say..

Comment: Im using catdoc-0.95.tar.gz package for xls2csv,can you help me in to this which libreary or paches for solving this problem.

Comment: @lenz can you suggest any solution for this problem

Comment: I don't have a patch for you, but I encourage you to file a bug about this issue. Active development of the tool lies back some 10 years, but the author is apparently still maintaining it (there was a bugfix last fall), so your chances aren't that bad. Go to http://www.wagner.pp.ru/~vitus/software/catdoc/, scroll to the bottom, and follow the instructions to log in to the bug tracker.

Comment: Or just send an email to the author; you can find his email address in the [commit messages](http://www.wagner.pp.ru/gitweb/?p=oss/catdoc.git;a=commit;h=38a2807d22ce1a08bc39b94e9072a9f8f52cd86f) of the tool's repository.